# Subdividing a general polygon in a number of small convex polygons

Tags: polygon, convex-polygon

I have a polygon P made of N vertices. I need an algorithm that, given P, subdivide it in a certain number of convex polygons each using at most M vertices.

Ps.
P is a 2D polygon. Furthermore, i can use a polygon triangulation, but i am interested in algorithms that subdivide P into convex polygons having more than 3 vertices (and, as said above, at most M).

Comment: Why not do something similar to triangulation, but only draw a line from the inner point to every Mth vertex?

Answer (score 0):

[Quadtree](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25555-mesh2d-automatic-mesh-generation/content/Mesh2d%20v24/quadtree.m) methods would be my recommendation.  Check those out.

Comment: I can't see how i should use a quad-tree to subdivide my polygon. Could you explain better your idea? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a data structure; it's an automatic meshing algorithm.